# How to generate a basis for a linear mapping in a complex field such that's it's matrix is Upper Triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T:V \to V$ be linear. $V$ is a complex vector space of dimension $k$. Then there exists a basis so that the matrix generated by $T$ under that basis is upper triangular. The proof is by induction on $k$.

But how to generate such a basis. The first step is that because $v$ is a complex vector space, so there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Tv=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb F$. So, take $e_1=v$ because then $T(e_1)=\lambda e_1$. So, in the first column of the matrix the rows 2 to n will be zero. Now if I extend $e_1$ to any basis of $v$ that basis may not be a basis for which the matrix is upper triangular. Then how to construct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint:

The transpose $T^*:\ V^*\to V^*$ has an eigenvector $e^*\in V^*$. The kernel $K$ of $e^*$ is an invariant subspace of dimension $n-1$ of $T$.

Comment: Thank you Professor . I am trying to arrive at a solution from the hint.